# C++ linux time freezes application

Tags: c++, linux, time

I am importing `<sys/time.h>` and using the

```
struct time_t *start;
```

A class has a member time_t *start; and a member function getETA() :

```
template <class S, class P> 
double Task<S,P>::getETA()
{ 
  time_t *stop;
  time(stop);
  return difftime(*stop , *start);
}
```

Also note that time_t *start is initialized in the class constructor.

Whenever I call getETA() the application freezes.
Even more interesting, I used the same structures and code in the main.cpp in the main loop, and apparently it also freezes the application:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
  ...
  time_t *start;
  time(start);
  ...
}
```

Am I using it the wrong way ? I remember in some application a long time ago, that is how I used it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've to pass a valid pointer to `time()` function. So why don't you do this:

```
time_t start;
time(&start);

time_t stop;
time(&stop);
```

That is, don't declare `start` and `stop` as *pointer*. Declare them as non-pointer, automatic variables.

If you declare them as pointers, then you've to do this:

```
time_t *start = new time_t;
time(start);

time_t *stop  = new time_t;
time(stop);

//...

//Must deallocate the memory when you don't need them anymore
delete start;
delete stop;
```

But I wouldn't suggest this. I would suggest you to go with non-pointer variables.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I was under the impression I could use a stack pointer for this, but oh well. Thanks again ! :)

Comment: @Alex, yes you can use a stack pointer, but you've got to initialise it.  `time_t start; time_t* p_start = &start; time(p_start);` would work as well, and is using a pointer to a stack variable.

Answer (score 5):

Change it to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
  ...
  time_t start;
  time(&start);
  ...
}
```

The problem is that the function was expecting a pointer to a valid `time_t`, but you passed it a `time_t` pointer that is uninitialised, which results in undefined behaviour.